# Javascript regex to validate a fully qualified domain name such that hostname is maximum 15 characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I have to validate a fqdn using just regex which fulfills the following criteria

The maximum length of a hostname can be lets say 15 (before the first '.')

For eg: `abcd.xyz.aa`
In this case I need to validate that the string before the first '.' is max 15 characters i.e. abcd is max 15 characters

`(?=^.{1,254}$)(^(?:(?!\d+\.)[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{1,63}\.?)+(?:[a-zA-Z]{2,})$)`

This was the regex I am using to validate FQDN. I am unable to figure out how to update this to fulfill the above condition.

Comment: Why not use a quantifier `{1,15}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `(?=^[^.]{1,15}\..*$)` to the front of your regular expression.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/8h624R/1)

Comment: Hi thanks for the solution. It almost works. I just have one doubt that by adding this I cannot validate something like abcdef(any string which does not have '.').

Comment: Figured it out (?=^[^.]{1,15}\.?.*$). Thanks